# A non-linear optimization problem with constraints

Tags: nonlinear-optimization

We have two constraints:
$$
    \left[p_1+ q_1e^{\gamma s_1 (1-\alpha_{11}^{*})}\right] \left[p_1+ q_1e^{-\gamma s_1 \alpha_{11}(n_1-1)}\right] \left[p_2+ q_2e^{-\gamma n_2s_2 \alpha_{12}}\right] = 1
$$
and
$$
n_2\alpha_{12}+(n_1-1)\alpha_{11} + \alpha_{11}^{*} = 1,
$$
subject to $$0 \leq \alpha_{i,j},\alpha_{11}^{*} \leq 1.$$
We are maximizing the function
$$
f(\mathbf{\alpha}) = \alpha_{12}.
$$
Here, $p_i + q_i \equiv 1$ for all $i$ (i.e. these are probabilities),
and the counts $n_i \in \mathbb{N},$ whereas all the other parameters ($s_i,\gamma$) are positive
(and $s_i$ are quite "large", if that is relevant).
When solving an optimization problem with some values of the parameters using `ampl`,
we get that $\alpha_{11}^{*} = 1$ and $\alpha_{ij} = 0.$ How to prove this formally?

EDIT: The first constraint is crucial to the problem studied.

EDIT': How to prove the above trivial solution is the only solution possible?

Comment: If you remove your first constraint, you have a linear programming problem. Have you checked the convexity of the first constraint?

Comment: If you require $p_j+q_j=1$, then why the exponential terms? The brackets in the first constraint will not be equal to $1$ unless the values of $\alpha$ are precisely as you said, so that all the exponential factors are equal to unity

Comment: What I mean is, $\alpha^*_{11}=1$ and $\alpha_{i, j}=0$ is an obvious solution to all the constraints. I am not at all certain that any other solution exists